# Woocommerce : How show product tab in single product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use `woocommerce` for WordPress. And i install it successful, but when open single product. I dont see tabs and reviews and comment.

Its show me this error :

```
Notice: Function woocommerce_sort_product_tabs() expects an array as the first parameter. Defaulting to empty array. in /home/vvvv/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php on line 1031
```

How can show that ?

Best wishes

Comment: Enter information about product into wordpress text editor and check 'enable reviews' under tab of advance in product data section in single product.it will enable tab on single product page.

Comment: I enable it but not show

Comment: check Enable ratings on reviews in woo commerce seeting at woo commerce setting >> products >> reviews

Comment: I do that and show me this error `Notice: Function woocommerce_sort_product_tabs() expects an array as the first parameter. Defaulting to empty array. in /home/vvvv/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php on line 1031`

Comment: Does your tab activated by make enable review from woo commerce setting?

Comment: Yes i enable review from woo commerce setting